# Swift IMAP и POP3

Tags: swift, imap

Работа с IMAP или POP3 на swift, интересуют библиотеки которые позволяют делать это на swift под ios, обыскал инет, нашел 2.5 либы которые это предлагаю и обе либы геморные, mail core не понимаю как ставить ибо xcode каждые полмесяца координально меняется и не получается идти по гайду с оф и не только сайта, есть ещё Postal но он просто не работает, ставлю по гайду и ничего, тем более он не обновлялся с 17 года, я вообще не уверен что он ещё работает, может кто-то занимался таким и может порекомандовать какой-то пакетик? Или же гайд как нормально уставить MailCore, ибо на сайте одна установка, по видосу другая, на форумах третья и не одна из них не получается

Comment: как насчет стандартного решения с `MFMailComposeViewController`?

Comment: Так оно же только на отправку

Comment: Вы не указали, что вам требуется и получение

Comment: IMAP и POP3 это и есть протоколы получения почты...

Comment: Да вы правы прошу прощения

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на сегодняшний день (7.12.2021) является использование либы MailCore, как установить ролик вот https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkpLqNN8xtU